# Discord.js - Storing each Individual's Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

### Background:

My bot currently sends questions and waits for other people's responses. Not sure if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869044/discord-js-counter-and-storing) relates or not considering I'm only temporarily storing the user's response with an array and then passing it into a function where it then gets written into a spreadsheet.

---

### The Problem:

I've noticed that if a user were in the process of responding to the questions, and another user intercepts it with the starting command `!start`, the bot would reset and only respond to the new user.

Image example of my current bot:
[image: betterCurrentVersion]

---

### Question:

Do I have to use some other software in order to make sure that the bot can respond to both the users or is there a different functionality I can use within `discord.js`? I know public bots have this capability.

---

### Expected Action/Output:

[image: exampleBot]

Hopefully, that image helps to clarify things. The bot is able to interact with both users instead of cutting off the previous operation.

---

### Methods Tried:

- moving the code inside a command handler, so the various commands could (hypothetically be executed individually)
- Part solution: `collecting` used to check if the bot is currently asking another person, if so, it sends a message in the channel to the person who responded.

---

### Code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'start',
    description: 'For data collection purposes',
    async execute(message, args) {
        num = 0;
        item = quiz[num];
        line = [];
        message.channel.send(`${message.author}, ${item.question}`);

        //filters if message = message author and is a possible option
        const filter = m => m.author === message.author;
        const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { max: quiz.length });

        collector.on('collect', async m => {
            newLine = line.push(m.content);
            await message.channel.send(`${message.author}, Thanks for participating in the survey!`);
            num = 0;
            item = quiz[num];
            line = [];
        })

        collector.on('end', collected => {
            console.log(`Collected: ${collected}`);
            // adds it onto the spreadsheet
            if (line.length != 8) { // checks if collector terminated before the actual time
                return;
            } else {
                console.log("Done with form!");
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the bot doesn't respond anymore? Your picture only shows the first user not saying anything anymore.

Comment: I've just edited it to include a better image to show that the bot doesn't respond anymore.

Comment: Can you add your code for this functionality? I guess you basically need to have several instances open and filter for the authors id, so it can't be overwritten.

Comment: Yup, just did. I also added comments that help to explain how it works. I've currently got global variables to store these items, would I have to shift to a more OOP method-oriented code to make it more dynamic? I don't have much experience with that tbh.